# How can I assign a list in a tuple in a dictionary?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and experimenting a bit but having trouble making a list into a tuple to use as a dictionary key.  Here's an example, which should make it more clear:

```
dict_of_lists_values = {}
dict_of_lists_values[('dog', 'cat')] = 10
dict_of_lists_values[('dog1', 'cat1')] = 10
dict_of_lists_values[('dog1', 'cat2')] = 10
dict_of_lists_values
{('dog', 'cat'): 10, ('dog1', 'cat2'): 10, ('dog1', 'cat1'): 10}
```

This works perfectly, and allows me to have a two values I can use as keys in a dictionary.  When I try to apply this to a list, I get an error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

```
dict_of_lists_values = {}
a = [22, 39, 0]
b = [15, 38, 12]
dict[(a, b)] = 'please work'
```

Based on my previous experiment, I think if I convert the list into a string it would work but I want it as it as a list not a string.

Is this possible?

Comment: Also, sorry if the title is confusing..I tried to think of the less confusing title(and the fact that I only came up with this shows how confusing this problem is :-)

Comment: This fails because the hash of a tuple is composed from hashes of each element.

Comment: I thought it converted it like it did with my first example.  I'm going to review my books on python tuples...Thanks for clarifying..

Comment: Strings are hashable; lists are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `tuple()` on a list to create a tuple with the elements in the list.

Answer (score 3):

No.  It's not possible to use `list` types for dictionary keys.  However, you could extend  `list`, make it hashable, and then use that new type.  (Though it's a bit cumbersome.)

```
class hlist(list):
    def __hash__(self):
        # Hash it somehow; here, I convert it to a hashable tuple ... and then hash it
        return hash(tuple(self))

l1 = hlist([1,2,3])
l2 = hlist([4,5,6])

d = {
    l1:"Hi.",
    l2:"Hello!"
}
```

Please note Sven's comment below.  Mutable keys are dangerous because their hash becomes stale if they are modified.

Comment: That's a very bad idea since the hash changes when the list changes.  If you use mutable dictionary keys, make sure the hash won't ever change.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Why wouldn't we want the hash to change if the list changes?  The question appears to seek a content-based key, not an identity-based one.  Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Here's an [example](http://ideone.com/1UEdb) to illustrate the problem.  If the hash changes, the dictionary object will no longer be able to find the key since its position inside the hash table was determined using the original hash.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Ah, very good point.  That was indeed an oversight.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries in Python can only have immutable/hashable keys.

Strings, numbers, and tuples are immutable, so they can be used as dictionary keys. Instances have a unique `__hash__()`, so they can also be used. But lists are mutable, so they cannot be used as keys.

Comment: Man, I'm sleepy. Got that backwards. Thanks for the edit Russell.